# Issue with mongodb-spark-connector: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get a connection between jupyter notebook (pyspark) and mongodb in an apache sparksession. The following error comes in and i do not know how to solve it.

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/db.coll") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/db.coll") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12-2.4.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.load. :
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$  at
>   com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.constructRelation(DefaultSource.scala:91)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)